# Why does Scheme have both list and quote?

Tags: scheme

Since (list 1 2 3) yields (1 2 3) and (quote (1 2 3)) yields (1 2 3), what is the rationale for having both?

Since Scheme is otherwise so spare, these must have some meaningful difference.  What is that?

Comment: "Since Scheme is otherwise so spare" - You might be interested to know that `list` is actually a derived form that can be defined by Scheme itself: `(define (list . objs)  objs)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the example you mentioned `quote` and `list` have the same result because numeric constants evaluate to themselves. If you use expressions that are not self-evaluating in the list (say variables or function calls), you'll see the difference:

`(quote (a b c))` will give you a list that contains the symbols `a`, `b` and `c` while `(list a b c)` will give you a list containing the values of the variables `a`, `b` and `c` (or an error if the variables do not exist).

Answer (score 5):

List creates a list, so (list 1 2 3) creates a three-element list.

Quote prevents evaluation. Without quote, the expression (1 2 3) would be evaluated as the function 1 called with arguments 2 and 3, which obviously makes no sense. Quote prevents evaluation and just returns the list, which is specified literally in its external printable form as (1 2 3).