# List of procedures in scheme

Tags: scheme

In scheme, I would like to be able to have a list of procedures that I could use on lists of numbers via map.

For example, say I have the procedure

```
(define (overten? x) (> x 10))
```

Why does this work when called with (foo '(1 2 11 12) '()) ?

```
(define (foo lst proc)
    (map overten? lst)
)
```

But this gives an error called with (foo '(1 2 11 12) '(overten?)) ?

```
(define (foo lst proc)
    (map (car proc) lst)
)
```

With the error being

```
The object overten? is not applicable.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `'(overten?)` is a list containing a symbol. Only if you evaluated `overten?` you would get back the procedure. You need to write `(list overten?)` so that arguments to `list` are evaluated (unlike `quote`).

See [Why does Scheme have both list and quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004786/why-does-scheme-have-both-list-and-quote)

Answer (score 0):

`'(overten?)` is not a list with procedures. It's a list with a symbol that *has nothing to do with procedures bound to that name in any scope*

You need to think evaluation:

```scm
overten? 
; ==> {procedure overten? blabla} 
;     (a implementation dependent representation of a procedure object
'overten 
; ==> overten? 
;     (just a symbol with name "overten?", nothing to do with the procedure object above)
(list overten? 'overten?) 
; ==> ({procedure overten? blabla} overten)
      a list where the first element is a procedure and the second a symbol with name "overten?"


(define another-name-quoted 'overten?) 
; ==> undefined
; 'overten? evaluated to a symbol, them bound to another-name-quoted
(define another-name overten?)         
; ==> undefined
; overten? evaluated to a procedure, then bound to another-name
```

The procedure `overten?` is not more `overten?` than it is `another-name`.
Here is an example where we use lists of procedures. It's an implementation of the `compose` procedure:

```scm
(define (my-compose . procs)
  (let* ((rprocs (if (zero? (length procs))
                     (list values)
                     (reverse procs)))
         (proc-init (car rprocs))
         (proc-list (cdr rprocs)))
    (lambda args
      (foldl (lambda (proc acc)
               (proc acc))
             (apply proc-init args)
             proc-list))))

(define sum-square-sub1-sqrt
  (my-compose inexact->exact
              floor
              sqrt
              sub1
              (lambda (x) (* x x))
              +))

(sum-square-sub1-sqrt 1 2 3) ; 5
```